# Jqgrid being cached I think after I clear it?

Tags: jqgrid

```
function clearJqGrid()
        {
            // get IDs of all the rows of jqGrid
            var rowIds = $('#messages').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            // iterate through the rows and delete each of them
            for(var i=0,len=rowIds.length;i<len;i++)
            {
                var currRow = rowIds[i];
                $('#messages').jqGrid('delRowData', currRow);
            }   
        }
```

So I run this every singe time BEFORE i make an AJAX call to fill this grid. However, if you then go up and sort one of the columns, the grid is then bringing back all the old messages that were in it from the previous fill. Without sorting, you only see the ones that should be there.

Is the Jqgrid caching its entries when it shouldn't be? Should my `clearJqGrid()` method be something else? I just made it this because I found it online, but do any of you have a better one?

Thanks!

Comment: `delRowData` only deletes data client-side. Are you trying to perform a client-side sort as well?

Comment: Could you include more full code in your question? Which datatype you use? `dytatype:'json'`? How you fill the data in the grid? Why you need at all delete any row data in the case? I suppose that you can make strange effects which you describe only if you use `loadonce:true` and switch the datatype to `dytatype:'json'` before you delete the local data. In any way the way which you use is one from the most slowest ways which exist. One can optimize it, but one need more information about the jqrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most effective way to remove all **local data** from the grid could be the code:

```
// get DOM element of the table
var myGridDomNode = $('#messages')[0];

// delete internal local grid data 
myGridDomNode.p.data = [];
myGridDomNode.p._index = {};

// delete all grid contain excepting the first dummy invisible row
var trf = $("tbody:first tr:first",myGridDomNode)[0]; // save first row
$("tbody:first",myGridDomNode).empty().append(trf);
```

In other situations the `GridUnload()` can be effective used which destroy additionally the column headers, pager and all grid elements. So to display the grid one more time you will need recreate it.

In the most cases you **don't need delete** the grid contain. After the ajax call will be completed the jqGrid will delete the grid contain itself. Only if you switch manually the datatype of grid from `dytatype:'json'` to `dytatype:'local'` and back you can need to do this.